# SBT native packager: Unzip artifact in %install

Tags: sbt, rpm, sbt-native-packager

I am using sbt-native-packager (0.8.0) with SBT 0.13.5. I have a zip file that should be unzipped as part of RPM installation. In a RPM spec it will be under `%install` section, where will I define it using sbt-native-packager? I can unzip the artifact and add the unzipped folder as `linuxPackageMapping` but I wanted to check if there is a way to include the zip in RPM and unzip it during installation.

Comment: A small note about how rpm works. The `%install` section of the spec file does **not** happen on package installation on the installing computer. It happens during package building and is where files that will go **in** the packaged rpm are put into the buildroot directory. Only the `%pre`/`%post`/etc. scriptlets in the spec file are run **on** the installing computer. (And generally you don't want to put new files down there because then rpm won't know your package owns them, unless you list them in the `%files` section as `%ghost` files.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for clarifying on working of `%install`.

Answer (score 0):

Beside Etan's comment, which says you shouldn't create new files (if not necessary) during your install. This is how you would place extra rpm scriptlets in your rpm. Also see the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html#scriptlet-changes)

```
rpmPost := {
  val prev = rpmPost.value.getOrElse("")
  Some(s"""|$prev
           | unzip magic-file.zip
           |""".stripMargin)
  }
```

**Update**

Also take a look at the [JavaServerAppPackaging Customize Docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_server/customize.html)

cheers,
Muki